# Can't find trait WeightInfo in this scope

Tags: weight, benchmarking

I've got the error:

> cannot find trait `WeightInfo` in this scope

I've added this in runtime:

```
impl my_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type WeightInfo = my_pallet::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}
```

And this in my lib.rs pallet:

```
pub mod weights;
pub use weights::WeightInfo;
```

with this also in config:

```
type WeightInfo: WeightInfo;
```

And of course I've generated a weights.rs file using the benchmark tool which looks correct comparing to the examples and other pallets.

Why can't the compiler find the trait for `WeightInfo`?

*Edit: I forgot to paste the exact output:*

```
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `WeightInfo` in this scope
  --> pallets/my_pallet/src/lib.rs:33:20
   |
33 |         type WeightInfo: WeightInfo;
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: you might have meant to use the associated type
   |
33 |         type WeightInfo: Self::WeightInfo;
   |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: consider importing one of these items
   |
23 |     use crate::WeightInfo;
   |
23 |     use frame_system::WeightInfo;
   |
```

Comment: Btw: I used the template hendlebars as explained in this issue: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/7390

Comment: Sounds good so far. You added `--template=.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs` to the benchmark command?  
If you could share the code, that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Yes exactly, I've used the master branch file : https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I've just created a git repo with the code: https://github.com/lucgerrits/pallet-error-for-stackexchange , the pallet is sim_renault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a pallet does not import the surrounding imports.
The fix is to add a `use super::*;` to your pallet like this:

```rust
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use super::*;  // Here
    #[allow(unused_imports)]
```

Also I don't see the maintain template in [your executed command](https://github.com/lucgerrits/pallet-error-for-stackexchange/blob/d7bc0a0080a926364880630ce26d2235b96893a6/pallets/sim_renault/src/weights.rs#L20). Therefore the next error is about the `()` type not implementing your `WeightInfo` trait. The maintainer template does that [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/618f26bc9fe1a5ae8ee0a485e4e24da3e5979af6/.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs#L89) for you.
Or you use `pallet_sim_renault::weights::SubstrateWeight<Test>` instead of `()`.

Comment: use super::*; did the trick ! Thanks !

Comment: Indeed WeightInfo trait was missing, but I did the benchmark again with use super::*;, now its all good :)